# Eloquent join 2 tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I am building an api that outputs json

so what i have is 2 tables

```
Categories Table
    id
    name
    nameAR
    nameTR
```

---

```
Items table
    id
    category_id
    nameAR
    nameEN
```

i the json output to be exactly like this because the android application is already published and this API will replace a static json file

```
{
"name" : *Category name*,
"nameAR" : *Category Arabic name*,
"nameTR" : *Category Turkish name*,
"items" : [

   {"nameAR": *Item Arabic name*,
   "nameEN": *Item English name*},

   {"nameAR": *Item2 Arabic name*,
   "nameEN": *Item2 English name*}

   ... etc
   ]
}
```

i know that i can do this:

```
$cat=Category::first();
$items=$cat->items;
```

to get every table in an individual variable but what i want is to get all categories with **Category::all()** and put all the items that belongs to the category as an object in an array called *items* in the category's object

***i do have my relationships configured**

```
Category : 
    public function items()
        {
          return $this->hasMany('Project\Item');
        }
```

---

```
Item: 
    public function category()
        {
          return $this->belongsTo('Project\Category');
        }
```

Comment: And what's the question? What have you tried?

Comment: i managed to join every item to the category manually but i just cant figure how to do it automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all categories with items that belong to those categories you may use:

```
$categories = Category::with('items')->get();
```

When returning collection as Json you will get what you want but you will have some extra columns (if you want you need to use `select` to choose only those you really need)

Comment: i've just found this but i am getting an empty array . 
although am pretty sure my relationships are ok

Comment: @AlhasanIQ Make sure you have valid items for your categories. For example for category with id=1, are you sure you have any items with `category_id=1` ?

Comment: i found the problem , in my query i have selected specific columns from the category 
**select('name','nameAR','nameTR')**
if i add the id column to the selected columns the query will work 
but i dont to add it . what choices do i have

Comment: @AlhasanIQ You need to always select columns that are used for relationship. However if you really need,you might remove them when returning to Android but I'm pretty sure that Android uses parser that will ignore unexpected columns so even if you return id it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

use map function

```
        $categories = Categorie::all();
        $categories->map(function ($cat){
            $cat->items=Item::where('category_id',$cat->id)->get();
        });
```